# Do event handlers for different buttons queue up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about handling of events triggered by clicks on different buttons:

Assuming we have several buttons pointing to the same event handler (attached through JQuery's "one" function )

If the first step in the event handler is to disable the event handlers of all the other buttons by calling JQuery's off -- Is it still possible for fast clicks on the other buttons to get queued up and execute once the event handler for the first button has finished executing? Even if the first button click removed the handlers for all buttons?
I am thinking that the browser might keep an internal event queue that is managed separately from the JavaScript thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firing of the event handlers is synchronous.  Animations, ajax, and other stuff (e.g. `setTimeout`) are asynchronous, but this is not true of the firing of events.  Therefore you don't have to worry about fast clicks firing an event before `.off` is reached unless the call to `.off` occurs after something asynchronous completes.